# Javascript onclick using a class instead of inline

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to do an onclick event using a class to enable the onclick, for a simple hide show. Yes I have seen similar postings, but none that answer my question specifically. Which is:

How can I toggle an onclick class like 'toggle' to hide and show content based off of an ID? So I can have id='blah' class='toggle' than it would toggle the div using ID 'blah'?

How can I have an anchor link like:

```
<a id="proc" class="coco button-link toggle" style="cursor: pointer;">See Our Proclamations</a>
```

I am using a simple javascript based on using an onclick event, but I want to not use an onclick event.

```
<script>
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

I tried to use something like this, but it definitely did not work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.toggle').click(function() {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
           if(e.style.display == 'block')
              e.style.display = 'none';
           else
              e.style.display = 'block';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately I understand PHP far better than I understand javascript.. Thank for any and all help!

Comment: Just to clarify: are you using jQuery in your project? or you want a vanilla Javascript approach? in the second script, you're mixing jQuery and native JS methods.

Comment: You say that you want to do an onclick and then you say that you want "not to use an onclick". Which is it?

Comment: In the last script, use `var e = this;` and it should work.

Comment: @mrlew I would prefer to use a vanilla javascript method.

Comment: @ScottMarcus , I want to the action of an onclick but use classes to do so so as to not use a physical onclick inline

Comment: To get rid on an inline HTML onclick event handling attribute, we just do it using '.addEventListener' in JavaScript as my answer below shows. You can acres the element and style it numerous ways, it can be with classes, ids, positions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's not the link that you want to toggle, otherwise once you click it, it would disappear and you'd never be able to click it again. It's the content area that should be shown or hidden.

Second, don't set the style as the opposite of what the style is, when you can just call `toggleClass()`.

See the simple code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Set up a common click event handler for each section's clickable header
   // Note the addition of the callback function's "evt" argument. All event
   // handlers are automatically passed a reference to the event that triggered them.
   $('.sectionHeader').click(function(evt) {
     
     // Just toggle the CSS class that hides the element on the element that comes
     // just after the one that got clicked. Obviously, setting up the HTML structure
     // correctly is what makes this work.
     $(evt.target.nextElementSibling).toggleClass("toggle");
   });
});
```

```css
section { margin-bottom:1em; height:20vh; }
.toggle { display:none; }
.sectionHeader { font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <a id="procShowHide1" class="coco button-link sectionHeader" 
     style="cursor: pointer;">Section 1</a>
  <div id="proc1">
                 Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations 
                 Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations                    Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations                    Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <a id="procShowHide2" class="coco button-link sectionHeader" 
     style="cursor: pointer;">Section 2</a>
  <div id="proc2">
                 Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations 
                 Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations                    Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations                    Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <a id="procShowHide3" class="coco button-link sectionHeader" 
     style="cursor: pointer;">Section 3</a>
  <div id="proc3">
                 Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations 
                 Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations                    Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations                    Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations Proclamations
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: How could I alter this so I could use it with several togglable items on a single page?